# Why does the "session.save_path" has no value on SunOS 5.1?

Tags: php

I use the same php.ini in 4 platforms (Linux, AIX, HP UX and SunOS), which the `session.save_path` has been configured with value "/tmp". Doing a `phpinfo()`, all platforms show the correct value (/tmp) except for SunOS 5.1, which is showing no value. Any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: Have you modified the correct php.ini file?

Comment: `phpinfo()` will also show you which php.ini file it's reading and any others that might be included via the scandir directive. Confirm that your configuration file is the only one being used

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version of PHP that is installed on SunOS 5.1 does not have that option available, or it is called something else on that version?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I am posting here

Comment: Sooooo, what version of PHP are you running on it?